# Isn't Leninism left wing?

Tags: socialism, leninism

> His administration defeated right and **left-wing** anti-Bolshevik armies in the Russian Civil War from 1917 to 1922.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Lenin

I thought socialism (or maybe Leninism) is left wing, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, so? I think I read a bonmot somewhere that the most vicious political fighting occurs between rival left-wing factions ...

Comment: That proves union of the left is not feasible

Comment: Of course it is. Communism, Socialism, Fascism and their evil siblings are all children of Marxism, which is clearly on the left of the linear political spectrum.

Comment: @Gary2 in general any question important enough to argue over has at least two sides. Just look at the number of schisms any major religion has experienced.

Comment: Note that there's an entire page [Left-wing uprisings against the Bolsheviks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-wing_uprisings_against_the_Bolsheviks).

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin You made a factual mistake there: fascism is not a child of Marxism and is fundamentally at odds with a number of key principles of Marxism. See also [Is Fascism Right Or Left Wing?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/24665)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You made the wrong assumption. The existence of a left wing party or faction does not prevent the existence of another left wing party or faction.